# Can l get a real date from input type=date not a string?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

l was wondering can l get a date type from a input `type=date`,because when l get value of this input in `js` l got string type,so i don't want that course l wanna do some arithmetic operators on this date(example:l want to get date from a input control and after in js to get date time now,so l can take away input date from current date and find a age of a person).So how l can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the input's `valueAsDate` property

```js
document.getElementById('tgt').addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(this.valueAsDate));
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="tgt">
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, other than valueAsDate mentioned in [Bravo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52960656/309412), you can pass it to Date.

```
let strValue = document.getElementById("myDate").value; 
let dateValue = new Date(strValue);
```